# How to properly detach a command?

Tags: bash, sudo, xdg-open, gksudo

I have this little script I use to launch a root Nautilus window (yeah, dangerous, but sometimes necessary):

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo --description "Launch a root Nautilus" -- sh -c "xdg-open / &"
```

This works, but the System Monitor shows that until the root Nautilus is shut down, I have not only a root-owned nautilus process instance, but also root-owned gksudo, sudo, and xdg-open instances.

I would ideally like to have just the root nautilus instance running, which is what I thought the trailing ampersand in the command-line was supposed to do.

How do I get nautilus to detach properly? Can it be done at all?

Comment: The way I'd usually suggest is to use `disown`, which is a bash-builtin, but I'm not sure you *can* detach the process from `gksudo`.Thus: `gksudo --description "..." -- bash -c "xdg-open / &; disown"`

Comment: That command works too well: it does kill gksudo and xdg-open, but no root nautilus gets launched either.

Comment: The one in the comment or the ones in the answer? The comment has a syntax error.

Comment: The comment line. The syntax error would explain the lack of effect: gksudo goes through its motions, but the shelled-out command fails. Without the semi-colon, we get separate gksudo and xdg-open:nautilus processes, and the gksudo line does not return until nautilus is shut down. The 'disown' is redundant with the ampersand and is ignored, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`disown`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins) bash builtin, I can get `xdg-open` to detach from `gksudo`, but cannot do anything about `nautilus`:

The command:

```
gksudo --description "Launch a root Nautilus" -- bash -c "xdg-open / & disown"
```

The effect:

```
$ pstree -ps $(pgrep -u root nautilus)
init(1)───lightdm(1095)───lightdm(1537)───init(1545)───xdg-open(29323)───nautilus(29376)─┬─{nautilus}(29378)
                                                                                         ├─{nautilus}(29380)
                                                                                         ├─{nautilus}(29381)
                                                                                         └─{nautilus}(29382)
```

Unfortunately, this leaves the `gksudo` hanging around, doing nothing:

```
$ pstree -ps $(pgrep gksudo)
init(1)───lightdm(1095)───lightdm(1537)───init(1545)───test.sh(29601)───gksudo(29604)─┬─{gksudo}(29605)
                                                                                      ├─{gksudo}(29606)
                                                                                      ├─{gksudo}(29608)
                                                                                      └─{gksudo}(29610)
```

If you won't mind a hack, this script can get rid of the `gksudo` process, assuming you can type fast enough:

```
#! /bin/bash

gksudo --description "Launch a root Nautilus" -- bash -c "xdg-open / & disown; exit" &
sleep 10; kill %1
```

If you can't type fast enough, adjust the `sleep` duration.

Comment: The processes detach from each other (in the sense that gksudo no longer is the parent of xdg-open), but nothing shuts down.

Comment: @Urhixidur I have already said as much, and given a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is imperfect but close enough:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
gksudo --description "Launch a root Nautilus" -- \
   sh -c "echo 'Password accepted'"
gksudo -- sh -c "xdg-open / &" &
PID_GKSUDO=`pgrep -n gksudo`
sleep 10
PID_XDGOPEN=`pgrep -u root -n xdg-open`
sudo kill $PID_XDGOPEN $PID_GKSUDO
exit 0
```

Some explanations:

```
set -e
```

This ensures the script exits if the user cancels out of the password prompt or if anything else fails.

```
gksudo --description "Launch a root Nautilus" -- \
   sh -c "echo 'Password accepted'"
```

This line won't return until the user has entered the password or cancelled out of the prompt. The `echo` command is inoccuous and just makes for nice feedback when the script is run from a command line.

```
gksudo -- sh -c "xdg-open / &" &
```

The `gksudo ... &` returns right away (because it detaches from the script process), regardless of an eventual password prompt. This is why we prompted for the password on the previous line, because we otherwise can't tell how long we'll need to sleep later.

Note also that the `xdg-open / &` will also detach from `gksudo`, so we end up with two orphans: `gksudo` (childless) and `xdg-open` (parent of the desired root `nautilus` process).

```
PID_GKSUDO=`pgrep -n gksudo`
sleep 10
```

Here we recover the `xdg-open` process ID (immediately available) and then wait for `nautilus-gdu` to initialize and the window to appear. If we did not wait, the next PID-fetching command would fail because the process wouldn't exist yet (`pgrep` would return an error 1 and the script would not proceed to the `kill` line).

```
PID_XDGOPEN=`pgrep -u root -n xdg-open`
sudo kill $PID_XDGOPEN $PID_GKSUDO
exit 0
```

Finally, we get the `xdg-open` PID and `kill` the useless processes before exiting the script.

Comment: Thanks for the attempts to help. I did not know of 'disown' before.

Comment: Umm...On further testing, the above works, but only if invoked from a command line. If run from the GUI, there is no longer a shared environment, which means every `gksudo` invocation will ask for the password. I can go as far as subordinating the second `gksudo` invocation to the first (by moving its command line into the first `gksudo`'s sh argument using `() && ()`), a really ugly kludge. But trying to chain the later `kill` invocations in the same way runs into other problems. Time to give up.